# What is the easiest way to backup and restore whole site (with all files and data)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, backup, restore

How to fully backup and restore my site just once using SharePoint Online?

Comment: Based on the variety of answers you've received so far, it may be good to expand on your question a little more with some information about your environment. For example, if you have a single team site that has a small amount of data in it, saving a site as a template may suffice. In my experience in working with enterprises with terabytes of content in SharePoint Online, that simply will not work.

Answer (score 0):

For SharePoint Online, you must use a third party tool. I hesitate to name any of them because I do not endorse any particular one, and I don't want to leave anyone out. I will name a few to help you get started though: Megalogix, AvePoint, CloudAlly, LeapBackup. Keep in mind that Microsoft also currently performs backups for your tenant and keeps them for about 14 days. If you need a restore done, you must create a service ticket with Microsoft. Using the third party software, you will be able to control when you backup, and expedite the restore.

Comment: Must you? Would this not be achievable with PowerShell?

Comment: You can certainly use the CSOM (Client Side Object Model) with PowerShell or managed code -- which is essentially what the solutions I mentioned do.  My assumption was that the asker was looking for a robust, out of the box solution (no scripting required). Maybe a bad assumption...

Comment: That makes sense - just challenging the wording for my own knowledge and those that tread in future. Thank-you very much for your response!

Answer (score 0):

Without using any third party software, you may leverage on [Saving site as template](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Create-and-use-site-templates-60371b0f-00e0-4c49-a844-34759ebdd989). However, please be aware of the following limitations:

- Site collection and subsite should be backed up separately
- Limited to 50 MB
- User values will not be restored if they are not added into the sitecollection beforehand
- DateTime for the Created, Modified will not be backed up

When I performed a backup and restore previously, I used this approach. For the size retriction, I used Open with explorer to extract out all documents first. This is for me to ensure that the remainder will be less than 50MB.

Comment: Also, this will not work on a site with Publishing features enabled